# How can I find the value of a non-repeating exponent tower?

Tags: exponential-function, tetration

There are ways to express the function $$f(x)=x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{x^\cdots}}}}}$$ with $f(x)=\dfrac{W(-\ln(x))}{-\ln(x)} $ for other function like this;
 $$g(x) = x^{-x^{x^{-x^{x^{-x^{x^\cdots}}}}}} $$
I don't know how to express in a simple function, but I can put it like.
$$ \exp\left({\frac{W(-\ln(y^y))}{y}}\right) = x$$
But for something that doesn't repeat like.
$$h(x)= x^{-x^{-x^{x^{x^{x^{-x^{-x^{-x^{-x^\cdots}}}}}}}}} $$
How could I write it as an implicit function? Or find the value of $h(e)$?

Comment: Is defined as -(x^x) and the next part as x^-(x^(-x)).  I thought it looked a bit cumbersome with all the parentheses

Comment: How is $h(x)$ defined? Are you asking about some $h(x)=x\text{^}(a_1x)\text{^}(a_2x)\text{^}(a_3x)\text{^}\dots$ such that $a_k\in\{-1,+1\}$ defines some non-periodic ("non-repeating") binary sequence?

Comment: I'm not sure how would I define the sequence, but it would be like 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1 . . .

Comment: Is there some specific example you're asking about? If so, how can the coefficients be defined in terms of $(-1)^{a_n}$? Perhaps something along the lines of $a_n$ is the $n$th decimal digit of pi? If the coefficients are indeed completely random, then there is no pattern of any sort to allow for any closed form to be found, as infinite tetration formulae rely solely on patterns.